# Deficient Numbers

Tags: c, programming-challenge, sorting, linked-list, factors

I have found the following interesting challenge on the web:

> **Deficient Numbers**
>   A number is considered deficient if the sum of its factors is less than twice that number.
>   For example: 10 is a
>   deficient number because its factors are 1, 2, 5, 10 and their sum is
>   1 + 2 + 5 + 10 = 18 which is less than 10 * 2 = 20.
>   **Challenges**
>   *Easy level*: write a program to verify whether a given number is deficient or not.
>   *Medium level*: write a program to find all the deficient numbers in a range.
>   *Hard level*: given a number, write a program to display its factors, their sum and then verify whether it's deficient or not.

I implemented it in C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define DEBUG 1

/*
  XXX EASY-OPTION IMPLEMENTATION
  A list data structure is used to store the factors of a given number.
  A simple boolean-like data type is then returned by the main isDeficient function.
*/

typedef enum bool bool;
enum bool {
  false, true
};

typedef struct ListElem ListElem;
struct ListElem {
    int value;
    ListElem* next;
};

typedef struct List List;
struct List {
  ListElem* head;
  int length;
};

List* listInit() {
  List* list = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));
  list->head = NULL;
  list->length = 0;
  return list;
}

ListElem* listAppend(List* list, int elem) {
  ListElem* newHead = (ListElem*) malloc(sizeof(ListElem));
  newHead->value = elem;
  newHead->next = list->head;
  list->head = newHead;
  list->length++;
  return newHead;
}

void listPrint(List* list) {
  ListElem* head = list->head;
  printf("list > ");
  do {
    printf("%i ", head->value);
    head = head->next;
  } while (head != NULL);
  printf("\n");
}

void listSort(List* list) {
  int inactive = 0, debug = 0;
  while (inactive < list->length - 1) {
    inactive = 0;
    ListElem* previous = NULL;  // Initialise pointers...
    ListElem* current = list->head;
    ListElem* next = list->head->next;
    for (int i = 0; i < list->length - 1; i++) {
      if (current->value > next->value) {
        if (i != 0)
          previous->next = next;
        current->next = next->next;
        next->next = current;
        if (i == 0) // Update list head...
          list->head = next;
        inactive = 0;
        previous = next;
        next = current->next;
      } else {
        inactive++;
        previous = current;
        current = next;
        next = next->next;
      }
    }
    debug += list->length - 1;
  }
#if DEBUG
  printf("Debug info: sorting toke %i iterations.\n", debug);
#endif
}

bool isInList(List* l, int elem) {
  ListElem* listElem = l->head;
  for (int i = 0; i < l->length; i++) {
    int value = listElem->value;
    if (value == elem)
      return true;
    listElem = listElem->next;
  }
  return false;
}

List* findFactors(int n) {
  List* factors = listInit();
  int tempRes = 0;
  int debug = 1;
  listAppend(factors, 1);
  if (!(isInList(factors, n))) // Avoid duplicates only when n = 1...
    listAppend(factors, n);
  for (int d = 2; d <= n / 2; d++) { // The <= operator is necessary when n = 4 or the iterations don't start...
    if (!(n % d)) {
      tempRes = n / d;
      if (isInList(factors, tempRes))
        break;
      listAppend(factors, d);
      if (!(isInList(factors, tempRes))) // Avoid duplicate entries when the divisor and the result of the division are the same...
        listAppend(factors, tempRes);
    }
    debug++;
  }
#if DEBUG
  printf("Debug info: %i's factors found with %i iterations.\n", n, debug);
  listSort(factors);
  listPrint(factors);
#endif
  return factors;
}

int calculateSum(List* list) {
  int sum = 0;
  ListElem* listElem = list->head;
  for (int i = 0; i < list->length; i++) {
    sum += listElem->value;
    listElem = listElem->next;
  }
  return sum;
}

bool isDeficient(int n) {
  List* f = findFactors(n);
  if (calculateSum(f) < 2 * n)
    return true;
  return false;
}

// XXX MEDIUM-OPTION IMPLEMENTATION

List* findDeficients(int min, int max) {
  List* deficients = listInit();
  for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    if (isDeficient(i))
      listAppend(deficients, i);
  }
  return deficients;
}

// XXX HARD-OPTION IMPLEMENTATION

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Error: arguments are not one!\n");
    return 0;
  }
  int n = atoi(argv[1]);
  List* facts = findFactors(n);
  printf("The factors of %i are:\n", n);
  listPrint(facts);
  int sum = calculateSum(facts);
  printf("Their sum is:\n%i\n", sum);
  if (sum < 2 * n)
    printf("%i IS deficient.\n", n);
  else
    printf("%i IS NOT deficient.\n", n);
  return 0;
}
```

What about it? In particular, I would like to ask you for a feedback about the List structure and the sorting function. Is their code readable and understandable? Could it be improved with regard to performance?

Comment: regarding: `printf("Error: arguments are not one!\n")` 1) Error messages should be output to `stderr` rather than `stdout`.  2)  when the error message is about the command line parameters being missing, It is typical to output a `usage` message similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s  factors\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: regarding: `printf("Error: arguments are not one!\n");
    return 0;`   Returning 0 from `main()` indicates success, but the program was not successful.  Suggest using `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  (both the constant and `exit()` are found in `stdlib.h`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The algorithm:

1. Well, `findFactors` is far too inefficient. Better do a prime-factoring, and then create the list of all factors from that.
2. If you need to do enough prime-factorings, consider pre-calculating all candidate primes, be it during or before compilation or before use.
3. Only use a list if you have to: Using and when needed `realloc`-ing a dynamically-allocated array is far more efficient and simpler in most cases. And it allows you to rely on `qsort()` for sorting.

#### Your code:

1. Avoid over-long lines, as horizontal scrolling kills readability. Yes, your IDE might allow for longer lines without scrolling or auto-wrapping, but it still makes things difficult. Even if everyone used an IDE on a big screen and gave the code-window the full screen-width, it slows reading considerably.
2. If you use the preprocessor for configuration, allow overriding by pre-defining.
   This:

   ```
   #define DEBUG 1
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   #ifndef DEBUG
   #define DEBUG 1
   #endif
   ```
3. You might want to upgrade to C99, then you will have a true boolean type. If you don't, stay with an integer. Emulating a true boolean type with an enum instead is painful.
4. If you want to introduce a typedef-name for a struct- / enum-name, consider merging that:

   ```
   typedef struct ListElem ListElem;
   struct ListElem {
       int value;
       ListElem* next;
   };
   ```

   becomes:

   ```
   typedef struct ListElem {
       int value;
       struct ListElem* next;
   } ListElem;
   ```
5. Anyway, the customary name for a `ListElem` is `ListNode`, which though the same length avoids curious abbreviations.
6. ["*Do I cast the result of malloc?*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) **No, we are writing C here.**
7. Getting any resource, even memory, can fail. Handle it, don't ignore it.
8. Also, prefer `sizeof expr` over `sizeof(TYPE)`, doing so couples size requested and the use of the memory, making errors less likely, whether at first writing or after re-factoring.
9. `listAppend()` is mis-named, it should be `listPrepend()`. I also wonder why it returns the new node, which the caller probably doesn't care about, and can easily and efficiently get anyways.
10. `listPrint()` has Undefined Behaviour for an empty list. `findDeficients()` for example can result in an empty list.
11. `listSort()` doesn't really have to re-order the nodes to sort the values. Not doing so allows for some simplification.
12. There is no reason to use the lists size to iterate over the whole list. That way, your code gets simpler and more efficient:

    ```
    bool isInList(List* l, int v) {
        for (ListElem* p = l->head; p; p = p->next)
            if (p->value == v)
                return true;
        return false;
    }
    ```

    The same holds for `calculateSum()`.
13. If you have to choose one of two expressions, you should remember that's what the conditional operator `cond ? true_exp : false_exp` excells at.
14. Consider marking all internal functions `static` to avoid exporting the symbol and encourage inlining.
15. Please output diagnostic messages to `stderr` instead of `stdout`, so the caller can separate them easily.
16. The error-message for wrong use should explain proper use. `argv[0]` contains the program-name for that. Try to follow convention with your text.

#### Some comments about the challenge:

1. The second level is only harder than the first if you take advantage of efficiencies of scale, as you should.
2. The last level is only harder if you insist on sorted output, and didn't use any container earlier.

Comment: Referring to the *Your Code* paragraph, point 8, do you mean that it is better a statement like `malloc(2 * 4)` instead of `malloc(sizeof(ListNode))`, considering that a `ListNode` will contain an `int` value (then, 4 bytes) and a pointer to the next node, which is another `int` value?

Comment: No, rather malloc(sizeof *pointer).

Comment: Okay, thanks. Anyway, using the pointer to the memory allocated just improves the code readability, or can also avoid errors (for instance, when the code is compiled on another OS)?

Comment: It certainly avoids errors due to manually calculating for the wrong platform. The other point was stronger coupling between space wanted and space requested than magic number respective sizeof(TYPE) provides.

Comment: Referring, instead, to the same paragraph, point 7, could this be a valid solution to manage memory allocation errors?
`List* list = malloc(sizeof list);
if (list == NULL)
    return NULL;` Or even, is it better to use something like the `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` function?

Comment: @rudicangiotti Yes to both. You can certainly write code with the assumption that allocation-failure is a fatal error. Doing so has the virtue of simplifying error-handling considerably. Signalling the error to the caller, in C mostly with the return-value, though `errno` is also used (mostly for supplementary Information), as well as out-parameters or rarely `longjmp()`, is preferred, especially in library-code.

Comment: Thank you again, @Deduplicator. Anyway, I have another question, this time related to point 11: what do you mean by saying that the`listSort()` function *doesn't really have to re-order the nodes to sort the values*?

Comment: @rudicangiotti I mean that the identity of the individual nodes is not actually relevant, only their position in the list and their payload. And in this case it is easier to swap the payload than swap node-positions.

Comment: In other words, since each node includes a value and a pointer to next node, it would be better and easier to swap actual values instead the linkages between nodes, is it right?

Answer (score 3):

in `main()`, there is a call to `calculateSum()` then checking if the sum is < 2n,  etc.

However, that same determination is made in the function: `isDeficient()`

for this:

```
typedef enum bool bool;
enum bool {
  false, true
};
```

you might want to use the header file: `stdbool.h`

ISO C forbids forward references to `enum`s

regarding:

```
List* list = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));
```

1) in C, the returned type is `void*`, which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

2) the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` and `realloc` can fail, so should always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

The use of a linked list is 'overkill'   Suggest a simple array

regarding:

```
    debug++;
}
#if DEBUG
```

using multiple symbols those only difference is capitalization can be very confusing (to the person reading the code) Suggest using unique names

for ease of readability and understanding:  1) Suggest using an indent width of 4 spaces as 2 spaces is very difficult to distinguish when using variable width fonts.  2) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

There is no provision in the code to input a 'range' of values to use for finding deficients.

regarding:

```
int n = atoi(argv[1]);
```

the function: `atoi()` does not indicate if an error occurred.  Suggest using: `strtol()`  as that does indicate when an error occurred

regarding:

```
#define DEBUG 1
```

it is much more flexible to use `-DDEBUG` as a parameter to the compile statement rather than hardcoding the value in the source code